# Google Cloud Instance loses connectivity over public ip

Tags: google-compute-engine, google-cloud-platform

I'm trying to debug an issue where my Cloud Instance loses all connectivity over its public static ip address. All services can continue to communicate over its private IP, but trying to access it publicly only leads into a timeout. The only thing that seems to fix the problem is resetting the instance.

Here's a graph, where the instance loses connectivity at 6am, up until we reset the instance:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/7NvMb.png

The instance, AFAIK, is setup properly as public communication other wise works. However this issue seems to pop-up 1 to 2 times a month.

Comment: Could it be related to a firewall (e.g iptables) or service configured on the instance which is blocking the requests to the instance? When you have this issue, have tried reaching the instance from different locations(e.g home, office)?